# Oracle Apex Interactive Report Header Filter Size

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I've been searching for a way to increase the size of the filter box (col header filter) on an interactive report with no success (not the dialog opened once you click on the filter option but the tinny box that opens up when you click on a col header title).
Does anyone know how to change that?

Thanks!

[image: filter - header]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left click the icon and inspect style in google chrome. That will show you what css is applied. Add that css to Page Attribute "CSS" > "Inline". The "!important" will force it to override other css. Original value was 20px, changed it to 40 so it is really visible, change it to your own needs.

```
.a-IG-controlsIcon, .a-IRR-button.a-IRR-sortWidget-button, .a-IRR-controlsIcon {
    --a-icon-size: 40px!important;
}
```

On a side note, I would not play with this - changing the default UI behaviour of internal components will make your apps less upgrade proof which might cause you and the developers that come after you headaches :).